# ArgumentError in Portfolios#sho Nil location provided. Can't build URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Until now I was able to create a new portfolio in my Portfolio App.

Now I can create portfolio, but when I need to open the created portfolio I am getting error:

ArgumentError in Portfolios#show Nil location provided. Can't build URI

And before I open the created portfolio there is no thumb_image as there should be. Does anybody have a similar situation?

Here is link to my github repository: https://github.com/djordje21/DjoloPortfolio/blob/master/app/views/portfolios/show.html.erb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

You should check if there is an image before trying to show it

```
<% if @portfolio_item.main_image %>
  <%= image_tag @portfolio_item.main_image %>
<% end %>
```

Are you providing a URL or an image directly ?

You should try with a URL.

If you want to be even safer, you can do this in your `Portfolio` model:

```
class Portfolio
  ...
  def image_url
    main_image.url || default_url
  end
end
```

And call `image_url` in your template

Comment: Thanks for quick answer!

I cover it with If loop, it removed the error but just because I want to continue without error until I find solution.
I'm providing a URL (at the moment I am using placeholder image)
Thanks for idea, looks good!

Comment: If condition removed the error but still I can not see main and thumb image.

Comment: What is the URL of the image you're trying to print to the screen ?
Is the URL accessible on the web ? Is it hosted on your backend ?

Comment: It is just a placeholder. Here is the link: 

https://github.com/djordje21/DjoloPortfolio/blob/master/db/seeds.rb

main_image: "http://placehold.it/600x400",        thumb_image:"http://placehold.it/350x200"

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I pulled your code and tried but the placeholder worked.
I'm not having the error, and the portfolio image shows up
Are you having any errors in the javascript console of your browser ? And in the network tab ? Are you reaching placeholt.it correctly ?

Comment: No, I dont have any errors in JS console, for sure I mess up with connection of files. 
This is my first app, important thing is that I removed error for now. Hopefully soon I will get idea where I was wrong and how to fix it.
Thanks for your time!